# Различие ссылок на класс

Tags: delphi, классы, указатели

Допустим имеем следующую конструкцию (1):

```
type
  PNode = ^TNode;
  TNode = class(object)
    ...
  end;
```

т.е. типизированный указатель на класс

и конструкцию (2):

```
type
  TNode = class;
  TNodeClass = class of TNode;  
  TNode = class(object)
    ...
  end;
```

TNodeClass же по сути точно такой же указатель на данный класс? Это в принципе то же самое, какая-то старая и новая запись одного и того же (т.к. первый подход часто встречается в старых книгах, а второй часто мелькает в более современных источниках) или я что-то недопонимаю? В чём принципиальное отличие и как правильно работать с тем и с другим?

Comment: Мне кажется простым, но понятным примером применения метаклассов является [этот](http://teran.karelia.pro/articles/item_4408.html)
Он в достаточной степени законченный.

Comment: 8 лет спустя после написания этой статьи мне вот не кажется она простой для восприятия :) хз как вы ее простой считаете :) зы: в реальной задаче там были различные алгоритмы экстраполяций и регрессий, емнип

Comment: Именно из-за этого вопроса, полез в поиск. Нашел эту статью (кажись четвёртая  в выдаче). Первые три оказались ни о чём. А по вашей вроде понятно. Можно git на пример по той статье выложить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Про `class of` написал @MBo. Kлючевой момент для фабрики классов - наличие виртуального конструктора.

А вот про указатель.

```
type
  PNode = ^TNode;
  TNode = class(TObject)
    ...
  end;

var 
  a,b: TNode;
  pa: PNode;
begin
  pa := @a; // указатель на переменную а
  a := TNode.Create;
  // теперь а указывает на экземпляр объекта TNode
  b := pa^;
  // теперь b указывает на тот же TNode
  if b = a then
  begin
    // we are here
  end;
```

---

> т.е. если мы пишем `a := TNode.Create;` `b := a;` `a.free;` то b тоже
>   становится nil, так?

Хм, нет, никто не становится `nil`. Вызов `.Free` ничего не обнуляет. Обе переменные указывают на один и тот же участок освобожденной памяти.

> если нам нужна не ссылка, а копия, то нужно или какой-то метод Clone
>   писать или перекрывать и реализовывать Assign?

Это - да.

---

> если мы пишем FreeAndNil(a); то и объект уничтожается и указатель на
>   участок памяти. Тогда в b указатель остаётся, на участок на котором
>   ничего нет, т.к. объект уничтожен. Почему тогда в отладчике по адресу,
>   куда указывает b мы видим данные, которые были в уничтоженном объекте?

После `FreeAndNil(a);` память освобождена, а переменной `а` присвоено значение `nil`. Но переменная `b` продолжает указывать на участок памяти, где находился уничтоженный объект. Этот участок памяти считается "свободным" и может быть переписан в любой момент. Но какое-то время в нем будут по-прежнему находиться данные уничтоженного объекта.

Comment: т.е. если мы пишем
    a := TNode.Create;
    b := a;
    a.free;
то b тоже становится nil, так? А если нам нужна не ссылка, а копия, то нужно или какой-то метод Clone писать или перекрывать и реализовывать Assign?

Comment: хорошо, а если мы пишем FreeAndNil(a); то и объект уничтожается и указатель на участок памяти. Тогда в b указатель остаётся, на участок на котором ничего нет, т.к. объект уничтожен. Почему тогда в отладчике по адресу, куда указывает b мы видим данные, которые были в уничтоженном объекте?

Answer (score 5):

Первое - указатель на экземпляр **объекта**, это, в общем, бесполезная вещь, т.к. экземпляр уже сам указатель. (Возможно, это какая- то аллюзия на объекты старого типа)

Второе - [class reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Class_References), класс классов или метакласс.

Широко используется во внутренних механизмах Delphi для **фабрики классов** - экземпляр конкретного класса создаётся с помощью class reference.

Наиболее частый пример - `Application.CreateForm`

```
procedure TApplication.CreateForm(InstanceClass: TComponentClass; 
                                  var Reference);
```

Например, `TForm1` есть экземпляр метакласса (классовой ссылки) типа `TFormClass`. А `Form1` есть экземпляр (конкретный объект) класса `TForm1`. Компилятор создаёт объект формы с использованием метакласса. Код по умолчанию в каждом VCL-проекте c формой (dpr, меню Project-View Source):

```
Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
```

Замечу, что код, который это делает - не знает о существовании `TForm1`, `TMainForm` и других форм, которые нам заблагорассудится написать.

Для использования классовых методов конструктор класса, как @Igor отметил, должен быть виртуальным, что в иерархии объектов VCL начинается с `TPersistent`.

Вручную экземпляр формы можно и явно создать с использованием конструктора `TForm1`.

`FindClass/GetClass` позволяет даже использовать строковое имя класса для получения метакласса (если метакласс существует и был зарегистрирован)

Comment: вы бы проиллюстрировали это кусочком кода с `CreateForm(fcls: TFormClass)` с созданием `fcls.Create(nil);` и вызовом вида `CreateForm(TMyForm2)`, стало бы понятнее, а не просто текстом написать

Comment: @teran А что станет понятнее при демонстрации кода?